# Certain Japanese Characters Missing with CJK*

Tags: pdftex, cjk

Whilst using CJK to write Japanese to a LaTeX document I am having issues where some characters are missing from the output. For example my .tex file looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}

悪6上手ルぜづて種当止タセ説当ね読寮クや減8様ケリトク認川るす差禁音策きがぜえ足94練ぴむびょ。

\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

Which it will output:

[image]

As you can see the first character 悪 is missing from the output. I need to use pdfLatex and have tried different combinations but I am unable to resolve this issue.

Has anyone got any suggestions or ideas on how I can continue using pdflatex and have that character appear?

Comment: `\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{ipxm}` seems to work better.

Comment: Ah, you legend, thank you. I will test with other characters etc.. to see if others go missing.